# Python Pandas: Calculate moving average within group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, moving-average

I have a dataframe containing time series for 100 objects:

```
object  period  value 
1       1       24
1       2       67
...
1       1000    56
2       1       59
2       2       46
...
2       1000    64
3       1       54
...
100     1       451
100     2       153
...
100     1000    21
```

I want to calculate moving average with window 10 for the `value` column. I guess I have to do something like

```
df.groupby('object').apply(lambda ~calculate MA~)
```

and then merge this Series to the original dataframe by object? Can't figure out exact commands

Comment: the moving averages would be less rows, which periods should they be assigned to?

Comment: It would be ideal to do like this: for period 1, the MA equals just value from period 1. From period 2, MA = (value_1 + value_2) / 2, and so on until 10. After 10, it's a normal moving average

Comment: I'm trying to use pd.rolling_mean(), but didn't figure it out yet

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `transform`:

```
df['moving'] = df.groupby('object')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(10, 1).mean())
```

The `1` in `rolling` is for minimum number of periods.

Comment: This is the recommended way: I was going to answer with `pd.rolling_mean` and got the deprecation warning. So, thank you for teaching me something today @zipa

Comment: How can I calculate Bolinger Band values within group using [talib.BBANDS()](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/92323/talib.BBANDS)? Follwing code gives an error. (BBANDS() returns a tuple (upper, middle, lower).) `df['bb_up'], df['bb_mid'], df['bb_low'] = df.groupby('object')['value'].transform(lambda x: talib.BBANDS(x))`

Comment: Space Impact's solution is 2x faster and gives same results.

Comment: @OrhanCelik Space Impact solution does not give me same result unfortunately

Answer (score 37):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#new-syntax-to-window-and-resample-operations) on `groupby` object directly as:

```
df['moving'] = df.groupby('object').rolling(10)['value'].mean()
```

The new pandas version throws an error when used direct assign to the column so use:

```
df['moving'] = df.groupby('object').rolling(10)['value'].mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`. No idea what's the problem...

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk It will work you can check this [`groupby.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#new-syntax-to-window-and-resample-operations)

Comment: This should be the preferred solution. No need to use `transform`.

Comment: I was able to use this approach to generate a Series, however, I get the error @AlexandrKapshuk mentions when trying to assign the Series as a column in the original df. I also note that the groupby.rolling link @SandeepKadapa mentions only generates a Series:
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'object': obj, 'value': randint(1, 100)} for obj in range(100)])

s = df.groupby('object').rolling(10)['value'].mean()

df['avg'] = s`

Comment: @SarahMesser The error is `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index` so you need to reset index. Use `df['avg'] = s.reset_index(drop=True) `.

Comment: That clears the error, but df['avg'] is entirely nulls for me. My pandas version is 0.24.2

Comment: @SarahMesser Thats because you have only one value in each group, check that `object` has only unique values that means only one value per group on which you are calculating rolling and because of this you are getting `NaN's`

Comment: Oops. I deleted the 'period' loop in my list comprehension in an attempt to simplify the dataframe and make the example minimal. Adding it back in fixed the nulls, as you say.

Comment: I added a shift(1) between the mean() and reset_index(), because I didn't want to include period-2's value in the calculation of period-2's mean... This seems to have jumbled up the values by shifting values across the multiindex, from one "object" group to the next. Small, manually-constructed dataframes also seem dependent on the original index. It's probably necessary to run `df.sort_values(by=['object', 'period']).reset_index(drop=True)` _before_ your groupby-rolling construction so that the indices are guaranteed to align.

Comment: The values can be added back in the wrong way if the dataframe isn't sorted by the groups, but if you just drop the new level, it'll work nicely:
`.reset_index(level='value', drop=True)`

Comment: In pandas 1.3.4 it seems the reset index is no longer needed.

Comment: This solution is 2x faster than zipa's accepteed solution and gives same results.

Comment: This will not work when the index of df is not 0,1,2,... as the index of `df.groupby('object').rolling(10)['value'].mean().reset_index(drop=True)` will be 0,1,2... (tested in pandas 1.0.1)

Answer (score 13):

The answers provided may not produce the desired results if you are grouping on multiple columns.

The following should cut it:

```
df['moving'] = df.groupby(['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']).rolling(10)['value'].mean().droplevel(level=[0,1,2])
```

Comment: This should be the top answer +1! (.droplevel can be replaced by .reset_index, btw).

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer from @Sandeep Kadapa:

```
df['moving'] = df.groupby('object').rolling(10)['value'].mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The reason for `reset_index` is because after `df.groupby` we end up with a Multi Level Index and at the assignment we will get error `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

Answer (score 1):

These solutions assume the dataframe is sorted in a particular way (by object and period). For example, if the data were organized in panels (by period and object), then the assignment will fail. One general solution irrespective of sorting order is the following:

```
df.loc[:, 'value_sma_10'] = df.groupby(by='object')[['object', 'period']].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1, on='period').mean().reset_index(level='object')['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a column as a chain method:

```
(
    df
        .assign(
            column_name = lambda x: 
                x
                    .groupby(['object'])['value']
                    .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(10)
                    .mean())
        )
)
```