# Moving average with pandas using the 2 prior occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I was able to find the proper formula for a Moving average here: [Moving Average SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53339021/python-pandas-calculate-moving-average-within-group)

The issue is it is using the 1 occurrence prior and the current rows input. I am trying to use the 2 prior occurrence to the row I am trying to predict.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'person':['john','mike','john','mike','john','mike'],
                    'pts':[10,9,2,2,5,5]})

df['avg'] = df.groupby('person')['pts'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2).mean())
```

OUTPUT:
[image: OUTPUT]

From the output we see that Johns second entry is using his first and the current row to Avg. What I am looking for is John and Mikes last occurrences to be John: 6 and Mike: 5.5 using the prior two, not the previous one and the current rows input. I am using this for a prediction and would not know the current rows `pts` because they haven't happend yet. New to Machine Learning and this was my first thought for a feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want shift per groups add [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to lambda function:

```
df['avg'] = df.groupby('person')['pts'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2).mean().shift())
print (df)
  person  pts  avg
0   john   10  NaN
1   mike    9  NaN
2   john    2  NaN
3   mike    2  NaN
4   john    5  6.0
5   mike    5  5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df['avg'] = df.groupby('person').rolling(3)['pts'].sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

df['avg']=df['avg'].sub(df['pts']).div(2)
```

Outputs:

```py
  person  pts  avg
0   john   10  NaN
1   mike    9  NaN
2   john    2  NaN
3   mike    2  NaN
4   john    5  6.0
5   mike    5  5.5
```